# Rails Mailer not working in production on website, but works in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm banging my head against a wall.

So here is my problem. Let's start really simple. I have a contact form in my app, it sends emails after clicking submit. This form works perfectly in development mode. **But for some unknown reason it does not work in production.**

Well, what would you do now? Check production.rb in config/environments? Already done. Actually more than that - I have tried sending a mail with the rails console in production mode on my VPS. **And it works.**

```
UserMailer.send_data(Deliverer.new(full_name: "John Smith", email: "john.smith@yahoo.com", message: "Hello how are you")).deliver_now
```

I have a model called Deliverer, purely for antispam purposes. After entering the rails console in production on my server and pasting this command, a mail gets sent to my mailbox, just as it is supposed to work from the website.

This is my production.rb file

```
require "active_support/core_ext/integer/time"

Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV["RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES"].present?
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  config.force_ssl = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ENV['DOMAIN'] }

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    port: '465',
    address: 'smtp.seznam.cz',
    domain: ENV['DOMAIN'],
    user_name: ENV['SMTP_USERNAME'],
    password: ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'],
    authentication: :plain,
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    ssl: true,
    tls: true
  }

  config.log_level = :info

  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]


  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.report_deprecations = false
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

This is the SMTP error that I found in /log/production.log

**Net::SMTPFatalError (550 5.7.1 Not authenticated, please use AUTH first.**

As I said, this error shows up only in production when trying to send the mail from the website. **Sending an email from the console on production works, the form from the website does not.** And as I said, everything works fine in development, both the console and the form itself.

And I have no idea what to do.

**TL:DR** The mailer works in development mode (both from the website and with the rails console). In production, the mailer works only in rails console, but not from the website.

Mailer in production after submitting the form from the website does not work, but works fine when using the rails console. No problems at all in development.

Comment: Could you show the corresponding controller code, please?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've managed to solve this problem.

For some unknown reason, Rails was failing to recognize ENV[] variables. I really don't know why.

But once I replaced ENV['SMTP_USERNAME'] with "username@domain.com" and ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'] with "examplepassword" it all started working and mailer sends emails to my inbox.

I got no idea, because entering rails console or irb and using

puts ENV['SMTP_USERNAME']

actually printed my smtp username, the exact same thing happened with password and other environmental variables. I got no idea what was wrong.

**EDIT**
Okay I've done a little bit of troubleshooting. It seems like only config/environments/production.rb has a problem with accessing ENV variables. I'm not sure why...

Comment: Oh I forgot. I'm using nginx with passenger and I'm launching it with rvmsudo, so Rails gets started as root and root doesn't have access to my env vars.

Comment: I've added my env vars to root, it still doesn't work. I'm seriously considering using dotenv instead of env variables.